# Debo hacer que la nave se mueva dentro del planeta, por ahora tengo esto

Tags: ensamblador, game, arm, assembly

Con lo que tengo hasta ahora solo ubica la nave dentro del planeta, pero no logro hacer que esta misma se mueva. Tengo las funciones para que lea la letra que ingrese el usuario, pero al tratar de vincularla con las letras "a","w","s" y "d" para que hagan sus respectivos movimientos no pasa nada, ya me frustre. Quisera saber como podría solucionar esto, porque me queda poco tiempo para terminarlo y si sigo trabado con esto no podré continuar.

```
.data
/* Definicion de datos */

planeta:
.ascii "+--------------------------------------------------+\n"
.ascii "|                   (Grupo 14)                     |\n"
.ascii "|--------------------------------------------------|\n"
.ascii "|        *** Intenta aterrizar en Argos***         |\n"
.ascii "|--------------------------------------------------|\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "|                                                  |\n"
.ascii "+--------------------------------------------------+\n"
.ascii "|    Puntaje:          |        Vidas:             |\n"
.ascii "+--------------------------------------------------+\n"
.ascii "|               Integrantes: Benitez               |\n"
.ascii "+--------------------------------------------------+\n"
longitudPlaneta = . - planeta

pedirLetra: .asciz ""
long_letra= .-pedirLetra

.text

/*subrutinas para mostrar por pantalla en formato caracter de texto*/

mostrarPlaneta:
    mov r7, #4
    mov r0, #1
        ldr r1, =planeta
        ldr r2, =longitudPlaneta
        swi 0
        bx lr

ubicarNave:
        ldr r3, =planeta
        mov r0, #5/*Fila coord. x*/
        mov r1, #35 /*Column coord. y */
        mov r2,#'V'
        mov r4, #53 /*cantidad de elementos por fila*/
        mul r5, r4, r0 /*r5= nro de fila * cantidad de elementos*/
/*calculamos el puntero desde el matriz[0,0]*/
        add r3,r5 /*r3= puntero a la fila de inicio de mi matriz*/
/*sumamos desplazamiento de la columna a la q queremos ir r1=2*/
        add r3,r1 /*r3= puntero a fila + coord. Columna*/
        strb r2, [r3]  /*escribimos el char en la coordenada */
        bx lr

letraIngresada:
        /*Leer letra ingresada por el usuario*/
        mov r7, #3
        mov r0, #0
    mov r2, #1
        ldr r1, =pedirLetra
        swi 0
        bx lr

moverNave:
         #Comparo si la letra ingresada es igual a a,w,s,d
    bl letraIngresada
        ldrb r3, [r1]
        cmp r3, #'a'
        beq letraA
        cmp r3, #'w'
        beq letraW
        cmp r3, #'s'
        beq letraS
        cmp r3, #'d'
        beq letraD

.global main

main:
        bl mostrarPlaneta
        bl ubicarNave
        bl mostrarPlaneta
    bl moverNave
        bl fin_programa

fin_programa:
        /*Fin del programa*/
        mov r7, #1
        mov r0, #0
        swi 0
```

Comment: Es importante que nos indiques el compilador que estás usando y la arquitectura para que podamos reproducir el problema. Mira [mre]

Comment: La arquitectura es arm.

Comment: Y el compilador?